# RxJS. Combine observables that emit less then 1 second apart

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

There are two observables that may be emiting together or separately: `stream1` and `stream2`.
I need my subscription to fire only if `stream2` fires less then 1 second after `stream1` does.

Any way to achieve that with RxJS?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a timestamp and `withLatestFrom` to decide which values to emit
Here I just filter such that only values that meet your condition pass through.

```js
stream2.pipe(
  timestamp(),
  withLatestFrom(stream1.pipe(
    timestamp(),
    startWith({timestamp: 0, value: null})
  )),
  filter(([s2, s1]) => s2.timestamp - s1.timestamp < 1000),
  map(([s2, s1]) => ({
    stream1: s1.value,
    stream2: s2.value
  }))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution really will only work with "hot" Observables because I'm subscribing to the second Observable only after the first one emits:

```
const stream1$ = timer(1000);
const stream2$ = timer(800);

stream1$
  .pipe(
    switchMap(val1 => stream2$.pipe(
      timeout(1000),
      catchError(() => EMPTY),
      map(val2 => [val1, val2]),
    ))
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

`timeout()` will emit an error when `stream2$` doesn't emit in less than `1s` and the error is immediatelly caught by `catchError` and ignored.

To use this solution with cold Observables you can turn them into hot.

```
const stream1$ = timer(1000);
const stream2$ = timer(1800);
const stream2$Published = stream2$.pipe(publish()) as ConnectableObservable<any>;
const subscription = stream2$Published.connect();

stream1$
  .pipe(
    switchMap(val1 => stream2$Published.pipe(
      timeout(1000),
      catchError(() => EMPTY),
      map(val2 => [val1, val2]),
    ))
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-mqudah?devtoolsheight=60

I think this is a rare case where using `publish()` is actually useful. Otherwise, a little shorter solution might be like the following that will work with cold Observables as well even though it's not as easy to understand:

```
const stream1$ = timer(400);
const stream2$ = timer(1200);

combineLatest([
  stream1$.pipe(timestamp()),
  stream2$.pipe(timestamp()),
]).pipe(
  // Check that stream1$ emited first && stream2$ emited less than 1000ms after stream1$.
  filter(([val1, val2]) => (val1.timestamp < val2.timestamp && (val2.timestamp - val1.timestamp) < 1000)),
  map(([val1, val2]) => [val1.value, val2.value]),
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-yfhyyh?devtoolsheight=60

However, it's probably not very obvious what the `filter()` does from quick glance and has some "cognitive comlexity" :).